# Angular4 : if datasource is empty, how to display table rows like "No record found"

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular4 : if datasource is empty, how to display table rows like "No record found".Please help

[image: Code screenshot]

Comment: No text as image please.

Comment: And show your code? What have you tried and where are you stuck at?

Comment: I am using angular material md-table , If datasource is empty I have to display 'No records found message' 
Any pointers How can we achieve this? I did’t found any attribute in angular material md-table doc to display message if datasource is empty.
https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview

Comment: Any update please..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show empty message in data table angular material, If no data found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149632/how-to-show-empty-message-in-data-table-angular-material-if-no-data-found)

Answer (score 1):

```
Use an ngIf on your table if there is no data.

<ng-template [ngIf]="!(datasourceCondition())">
          <md-cell><h1> No Record found </h1>
           </md-cell>
    </ng-template>
```

Comment: How can we use ngIf in md-table with datasource? any online link.Please

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to display a full overlay on the table with a message that there is No Data then you can try the following approach.

Enclose the matTable and the overlay divs in a div which has relative position. Now set the position of the overlay divs to be absolute and set their width and height to 100%. The overlay div will display cover the full table.

Declare Boolean variables to toggle the display of the overlays while assigning data to the table.

HTML

```html
<div class="grid-div">
  <div class="grid-overlay" [hidden]="!isNoData">
    <div class="grid-overlay-msg">
      No data msg
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-overlay" [hidden]="!isLoading">
    <div class="grid-overlay-msg">
        Loading msg
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
    ...
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.grid-div {
  position: relative;
}

.grid-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.grid-overlay-msg {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40vh auto 0;
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is some example that hopefully helps you to hide your datatable if no data was found. You will need to add `*ngIf="dataSource.data.push()"`.

Based on your code...

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="!dataSource.data.push()">No past invoices found!</div>

  <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" mdSort *ngIf="dataSource.data.push()">

    (... rest of your code)

  </md-table>
  (... rest of your code)
</div>
```

***UPDATE:***

If you are using **@ViewChild**, i.e. for the matSort ability, the ***ngIf** won't work! You then need to use **[ngClass]='!isLoading ? "visible": "hidden"'** or something similar.

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="!dataSource.data.entries()">No past invoices found!</div>

  <md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" mdSort [ngClass]='!isLoading ? "visible": "hidden"'>

    (... rest of your code)

  </md-table>
  (... rest of your code)
</div>
```

Where in my case, **isLoading** is a simple function that checks for true or false.

Then in your scss/css file you will need to add the two classes **.hidden** and **.visible**

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
.visible { visibility: visible; }
```

Hope that help's you!

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of angular material you can do something like below

```
<tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
 <td class="mat-cell" colspan="9999">
  No data matching the filter
 </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `"@angular/material": "13.1.2"`, you can show empty message as

```
<tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
  <td class="mat-cell" [attr.colspan]="displayedColumns.length">
    No data matching the filter.
  </td>
</tr>
```